# How to change port that HSQLDB server listens on

Tags: java, network-programming, port, hsqldb

I am starting a HSQLDB server programmatically, however I am getting port conflicts when I try an run the HSQLDB server in conjunction with a web application that I am developing. I get the following error on the webapp side

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

& I get this error on the database server side:

```
org.hsqldb.HsqlException: Client driver version greater than '-1852.-79.-80.-35' is required.  HSQLDB server version is '2.3.2'
        at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.server.ServerConnection.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.server.ServerConnection.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm not sure why I get this error. However, when I looked at the ports used by the webapp and HSQLDB, I found that they both use 9001 so I assume the issue is to do with conflicting ports and not about HSQLDB versions. However, I'm not certain about that.

I understand that the default port number used by HSQLDB is 9001 and I've tried to change this with the following code by setting the port to be used to 9137.

```
    public void startDBServer() {
    HsqlProperties props = new HsqlProperties();
    props.setProperty("server.database.0", "file:" + dbLocation + "webappdb;");
    props.setProperty("server.dbname.0", "webappdb");
    props.setProperty("server.port", "9137");
    dbServer = new org.hsqldb.Server();
    try {
        dbServer.setProperties(props);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return;
    }
    dbServer.start();
}
```

However, when I then try and start the database server I get the following error stacktrace:

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect2015-04-27 11:42:02,306 INFO
 [Thread-2] server.DatabaseWorker (DatabaseWorker.java:20) - Database server is Running

        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
        at rideabike.server.DatabaseManager.getDBConn(DatabaseManager.java:37)
        at rideabike.server.DatabaseWorker.run(DatabaseWorker.java:18)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.hsqldb.ClientConnection.openConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ClientConnection.initConnection(Unknown Source)
        at org.hsqldb.ClientConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at org.hsqldb.server.HsqlSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
        ... 10 more
```

Is there anything further I need to do to try and change the port that the HSQLDB server uses? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is your connection URL on the client?

Comment: It's this: `"jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/webappdb"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the default port on the server, you need to specify the port in the connection URL:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9137/webappdb
```

Comment: Cheers, it works fine now! using `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://127.0.0.1:9137/webappdb` did the trick.

Comment: You figured it out, and I have corrected the answer.